# How insert a large array's values into an object in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose an array is

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ...];
```

and an object is

```
var obj = {};
```

How would I insert all of the array's values into an object with key.
The output would be:

```
{
  0:1,
  1:2,
  2:3,
  3:4,
  4:5,
  5:6,
  6:7,
  7:8,
  8:9,
  9:10,
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Object.assign` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.assign), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) for that:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let obj = {};
Object.assign(obj, arr);
console.log(obj);
```

That works because standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html),<sup>1</sup> and array indexes are own properties of the array. `Object.assign` copies own properties from a source object (or several source objects) to a target object.

Since it's from ES2015 (aka "ES6"), as you asked, it requires a polyfill on older browsers.

---

<sup>1</sup> *That's a post on my anemic little blog.*

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loop:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var obj = {};
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    obj[i] = arr[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let obj = {};

arr.forEach((item, i) => {
 obj[i] = item;
});

console.log(obj);
```